# Python ctypes error: OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I was trying to import a C function into Python using ctypes as a dll file, I get an error.
For example, C function:

```
int mul(int a, int b) {return a*b;}
```

and convert to dll:

```
gcc main.c --shared -o main.dll
```

and import into python:

```
import ctypes
myDLL = ctypes.CDLL('C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\main.dll')
```

I got this error using Spyder IDE (anaconda):

```
  File "C:\Users\Username\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 2, in <module>
    myDLL = ctypes.CDLL('C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\main.dll')

  File "D:\obj\windows-release\37amd64_Release\msi_python\zip_amd64\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

and same error using VSCode:

```
    myDLL = ctypes.CDLL('C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\main.dll')
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Note that I'm using Windows 10 x64.

Comment: changing ides doesnt change your code.

Comment: Maybe you are using 32-bit Python with 64-bit GCC, or the other way round? Also I think `--shared` should normally be `-shared` but I don't really know if it makes a difference.